# Fetch Parent & Child data using query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

(1) **taxes**: Parent table

```
id title
1   service tax
2   vat
```

(2) **cess_taxes**: Child table

```
id  tax_id   title
1      2    cess vat
2      1    cess service
3      1    add. service
```

**I want below data,**

```
id title*
1 service tax (parent)
2 cess service (child)
3 add. service (child)
4 vat (parent)
5 cess vat (child)
```

How can i get data with  using query???

I have tried with left, right & inner join

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, c.id, c.title
FROM `taxes` AS t
LEFT JOIN cess_taxes AS c ON c.tax_id = t.id
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @rn:=0;
SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank, title,id
FROM (
  SELECT title,id
  FROM taxes

  Union

  SELECT c.title,
         case when t.id=1 then 1.5 else 3 end 
  FROM cess_taxes c
  inner join taxes t
    on t.id=c.tax_id


) t1
Order By id
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab83e/21)

Comment: I an getting error in order by clause & if i remove order by it gives me wrong result. I want parent->child->parent->child. Your result is parent->parent->child->child.

Comment: Its working fine but i have one query. If i change order by id desc then it will be vat->cess vat->service tax->add. service->cess service.Which i needed otherwise its perfect.